# Database cordova access data outside of the or ipa apk

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, cordova

I wonder if there is a way to access and view recorded data from a database [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) data

I have a mobile app (android and ios) I know I can view the logs using log or alert, but is there any way to view these data on the device either by an application or other means? Native android applications used SQLite Database Browser but not with the cordova.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not you using Restful web service instead SQLite Database Browser? You can request and response your data using JSON.

Example

```
formData = {
    // all your parameters here
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://www.example.com/test",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        //success handling
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```

You can learn how to make simple restful here.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

If you still not understand about it, feel free to download my source code at github.

https://github.com/datomnurdin/service-finder-mobile

Enjoy!!